# Can this be done in one RE query?

Tags: regex, python-3.x

I am trying to scan some text to pick out a typical Html `<a>` tag for jpg or png files in the href attribute using:

```
'<a.*?href=\s*?([\'"])(.*?\.(?:jpg|png))\\1'
```

The above will, however, also give the wrong result when the source string is:

```
...<a href='http://a.b.c/x/y'>xxx</a><img src='abc.jpg'>....
```

It will match: `<a href='http://a.b.c/x/y'>xxx</a><img src='abc.jpg'>`.

My simple mind tells me I could first try to capture the `href` value, and then test to see if it ends with 'jpg' or 'png'.  Is there a more elegant way doing it with one RE in one go?

Comment: `href` or `src` attribute?

Comment: Don't use regex to parse HTML. Use an HTML parser instead. The one which comes included with Python should do.

Comment: Thanks for all the answers.  Yes, I am looking for the `href` value in an `a` tag, and not the `src` in an `img` tag.  HTMLParser looks interesting but it would mean a redesign of my existing application.  Will certainly use it for new work. I solve my problem by first getting the `href` value and then checking for `endswith`.

Answer (score 0):

Try this

```
<img src='.+?\.(jpeg|jpg|png).+?\>
```

[Demo](https://regex101.com/r/cV0gX3/1)